# Sticky menu when scrolling over adsense

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to create a sticky menu for a blog using jQuery. The menu works just how I need it, but the problem is when I scroll down on a page with adsense, the menu will go under that ad.

What I'm missing?

Here is my jquery function:

```
$(function(){
   var stickyRibbonTop = $('#mainmenu').offset().top;        
   $(window).scroll(function(){
        if( $(window).scrollTop() > stickyRibbonTop ) {
            $('#mainmenu').css({position: 'fixed', top: '0px'});
        } else {
            $('#mainmenu').css({position: 'static', top: '0px'});
        }
    });
});
```

and here I have a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7zb920bb/

Comment: You need to set the z-index of the #mainmenu higher than that of the ad.

Comment: That was the solution. Thank you guys. Monkeyinsight, you should post it as an answer not as a comment to be able to chose it as a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem...

I added the css property: `-webkit-transform: translateZ(0)` to the `.sticky` class.

It worked like a charm!